# Drive Explorer Using JTree

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a Drive explorer with jcheckbox selection which will display all drives, folders and files of a computer using JTree just like as windows file explorer:

[image]

This much I have done:

[image]

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    DefaultMutableTreeNode nodes;
    public NewJFrame() {
        nodes = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root", true);
        addRoots(nodes);
        initComponents();
        jTree1.setRootVisible(false);

    }

    public void addRoots(DefaultMutableTreeNode parent){
        File roots[] = File.listRoots();
        for(File root: roots){
            DefaultMutableTreeNode child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(root);
            child.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("test"));
            parent.add(child);
        }
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTree1 = new javax.swing.JTree(nodes);
        //.......
        //.......
    }
```

}

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: See [FileBrowser](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui) from @AndrewThompson from some ideas. And please _do_ actually ask a question, as this is a Q&A site. Your post seems to be more of a personal desire than an actual question

Comment: If I create the JTree after creating all nodes for the tree then it takes too much time. like 5 munites. I want to create it dynamically. When some one will click on C:\ then only it will add all directories and files under C:\ dynamically.

Comment: The code linked by @peeskillet builds the tree dynamically.  Did you run it?

Comment: This specification or requirement appears to be off-topic because it is about a specification or requirement as opposed to an answerable question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem (dynamically adding nodes -> described in the comments), you can do it with something like **dummy** nodes and TreeListener.
Dummy-Nodes (in this case) are used to **fake** existing children.
In TreeNodeExpand-Event, you can check if the expanded node has only a dummy as child and then you can create the REAL child nodes on-the-fly.

That means, for each Folder you get, you will create a new node which directlcy includes a DUMMY child node (to fake existing children).
Then, when expand, remove the dummy node and add the REAL Nodes. (same with all folder you get for the current directory)